# UIview displays half screen IOS7

Tags: ios, uiview

Hi in my application have i have popup view . I have made transparent background and I'm using UIView on top of it but in simulator its showing only half in the screen. like below images.

This is in my UIviewcontroller image

[image]

In simulator its showing like this.

[image]

Comment: If you are using storyboard that show screen of storyboard.

Comment: Under Attribute Inspector-> Simulated Metrics,Set the view size to freeForm and resize the views it will work .

Comment: @CRDave first image is my storyboard image

Comment: IMO, you have autolayout on. please share storyboard .

Comment: U want to show viewcontroller as popup. Am i getting right?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your simulator to 3.5 Inch, because from what I see you haven't add autolayout to your Views to support 4 Inch.

Learn more about [Autolayout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

Comment: pl in 4 inch its working f9 ihave set autorezing also but still its not working

Comment: I don't get you clearly, you mean it works OK in 4 inch? Can you provide a screenshot of the Storyboard on the Document Outline for your viewController? If it's hidden click on the arrow on bottom left of storyboard to show it.

Answer (score 0):

You could go for the code below:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  backgroundButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];  //Background button to handle tap outside popup view

  [backgroundButton addTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

-(void)tapDetected /* When user tap outside popup view so as to dismiss the view*/
{
  [backgroundButton removeFromSuperview];
  [tempView removeFromSuperview];
}

-(void)buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender /*To create and open popup view */
{
  [self.view addSubview:backgroundButton];

  tempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 100, 300, 300)]; //PopUp View
  [tempView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]]; 

  [backgroundButton addSubview:tempView];

  [tempView setAlpha:1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the registration controls (UILabel and UItextviews) are added on self.view instead on the view that is of half screen size.

Comment: please tell in 4inch its working f9 is only not working in 3 inch please tell how to resolve this one

Comment: Check if your controls are added on the half screen sized view. Also make sure they are pinned to aligned from top instead of bottom.